# Задача по e-olymp C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, олимпиада

Не могу решить эту задачу (проходит 10 из 12 проверок): [Задача №33](https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/33)

Подскажите, что надо поменять, что бы программа прошла?

Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool check(int num){
    while(num > 0){
        if(num % 100 == 13) return false;
        num /= 10;
    }
    return true;
}

int a, b, res = 0;
const int N = 500000;
int lp[N + 1];
int pr[N+1], e = 0;
int main() {
    cin >> a >> b;
    for (int i = 2; i <= b; ++i) {
        if (lp[i] == 0) {
            lp[i] = i;
            pr[e++]=i;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j<(int)e && pr[j] <= lp[i] && i*pr[j] <= b; ++j)
            lp[i * pr[j]] = pr[j];
    }
    for (int i=0;i<=e;i++)
        if (pr[i] >= a&&pr[i] <= b && check(pr[i])){
            res++;
        }


    cout << res << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Abyx помочь решить что не так в коде...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Только что [решил](https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/submissions/3648118) :)

Они в этих примерах дают `a > b`.

Добавьте в код после

```
cin >> a >> b;
```

что-то типа

```
if (a > b) { int k = a; a = b; b = k; }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло!